# Making table from json nested dictionary

Tags: python

I've a nested dictionary in json format for which I want to create html tables to send in an email according to key :

converting it into html table is where I'm stuck

```
{"test.txt": {"apple": "554", "banana": "23"}, "example.txt": {"apple": "551", "bannan": "2"}}
```

Tables should be like : Basically key as header

```
------------ 
 test.txt
------------
```

apple       554

banana      23

Comment: What have you already tried? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate throught your data structure:

```
>>> for n, values in data.items():
...     print(f"------------\n{n}\n------------")
...     for k, v in values.items():
...         print(k, v)
... 
------------
test.txt
------------
apple 554
banana 23
------------
example.txt
------------
apple 551
bannan 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"test.txt": {"apple": "554", "banana": "23"}, "example.txt": {"apple": "551", "banana": "2"}}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
       test.txt example.txt
apple       554         551
banana       23           2
```